# Find the maximal interval on which a unique solution of IVP

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Determine the maximal number $h_0 > 0$ so that Picard’s theorem guarantees the
existence of a unique solution on $[−h_0, h_0]$ of the initial value problem
$$y'(x) = x^\frac{1}{3}(1 + y^2(x))$$ $$y(0) = 0$$
Does this interval agree with the maximal interval on which a unique solution
exists?

I've used the Lipschitz condition to solve the first part of the question, and gotten $h_0 = \frac{1}{2}^\frac{3}{4}$

For the second part of the question, I've tried to use solve the ODE analytically by separation of variables. I got
$y = tan(\frac{3}{4}x^\frac{4}{3} +c)$ but was confused because plugging in $y(0)=0$ seems to give infinite solutions?

Would really appreciate some help, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using separation of variables, the general solution becomes $y = \tan\left(\frac 34 x^{4/3}\right)$. This leads to the maximal interval $\left]0, \left(\frac{2 \pi }{3}\right)^{3/4}\right[ \approx ]0, 1.74098[.$

---

Separation of variables first leads to a general solution implicitly determined by the relation $$\arctan y = \frac 34 x^{4/3} + C$$

Substituting $x$ and $y$ by zero (because $y(0)=0$) we get $C=0$.

Comment: Thank you! Please see the edit I made above, that's what I thought but I'm confused about plugging in the initial conditions

Comment: Yes but what about the periodicity of tan? Wouldn't pi and 2pi etc also work?

Comment: The constant $C$ is computed from the implict expression, before you compute the tangent and have an explicit solution, so there is no periodicity involved.